# Asymptotic Expansion of the Bessel-Integral Function

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

The Bessel-Integral function of order $\nu$ is defined by the formula $$\text{Ji}_{\nu
   }(z)=\int_{\infty }^z
   \frac{J_{\nu }(t)}{t} \, dt , | \arg (z)| <\pi$$

How do we derive the asymptotic approximation $$\text{Ji}_{\nu }(x)\approx
   \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi  x}}  \frac{\sin \left(x-\frac{\nu 
   \pi }{2}-\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)}{x} (x>0)$$

Comment: Spontaneously: replace $J_\nu(t)$ with almost any of the common integral representations, interchange the order of integration, and look for stationary phase.

Comment: Slightly less spontaneously: based on the shape of the asymptotics you want, an integral representation like (Gradshteyn-Ryzhik 8.411.11) $J_\nu(t) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \sin(t \cosh \xi - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} ) \cosh(\nu \xi) \, d \xi$ ought to do the trick. If you then locate a stationary phase around $x \approx t \cosh \xi$, you should get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Two options. Either, as suggested in the comments, replace $J_\nu(t)$ with an integral representation like (Gradshteyn-Ryzhik 8.411.11)
$$ J_\nu(t) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \sin\Bigl(t \cosh \xi - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} \Bigr) \cosh(\nu \xi) \, d \xi $$
and play stationary phase/saddle point method/Laplace method games.

Or, if you're lazy, take the word of someone (like the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17#E3)) who has already done this to $J_\nu(t)$ itself, getting (for $t$ large compared to $\nu$)
$$ J_\nu(t) \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}} \cos\Bigl( t - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr ). $$
Per the DLMF asymptotic, the error in this approximation saves a power of $t$ compared to this leading term (i.e., the error is $O(t^{-3/2})$) whence integrating it against $1/t$ contributes $O(x^{-3/2})$.

Insert this into
$$ \mathrm{Ji}_\nu(x) \approx \int_{\infty}^x \frac{J_\nu(t)}{t} \, d t = \int_{\infty}^x \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}} \frac{1}{t} \cos\Bigl( t - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr ) \, d t $$
and integrate by parts to get
$$ \mathrm{Ji}_\nu(x) \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \frac{\sin(x - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} )}{x} + \int_\infty^x \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t^5}} \sin\Bigl( t - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \Bigr) \, d t. $$
Note that the integral at the end is $O(x^{-3/2})$, and so is the error from the asymptotic expansion of the Bessel function by the aforementioned power savings.

Comment: Perhaps it is useful to add that the last integral is $\mathcal{O}(x^{ - 3/2} )$. Note also that the error coming from the replacement of the Bessel function by its leading order asymptotics also has the same order of magnitude.

Comment: @Gary Both of these are fair and correct points. I (somewhat cheekily) assumed OP was happy with a pretty heuristic argument, what with $\approx$ and all.

Comment: In any case, I've added notes to the above effect.

Comment: Yes, certainly $\approx$ cannot be replaced by $\sim$ since the $\cos$ can vanish sometimes giving that $J_\nu$ is asymptotic to $0$ which makes no sense.